# How do I get rid of error Object variable not set (Error 91)?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code and the error is occuring on the line with bidRow assignment. I've been trying to go variable by variable to see if it is an error there but doesn't seem to be the problem. I can't figure out why it doesn't work as it is almost the same as the bidCol assignment except it is searching for a double instead of a string. I checked the syntax for the Find method [Link to Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) which says that it accepts all VBA data types. Any help would be greatly appreciated :).

```
Function getWOMOSO(ByVal bidNum As Double, ByVal partSheet As Worksheet)
    Dim womoso As Double
    Dim bidRow As Long
    Dim bidCol As Long
    Dim womosoCol As Long
    Debug.Print (bidNum)
    bidCol = partSheet.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="BID").Column
    bidRow = partSheet.Cells(1, bidCol).EntireColumn.Find(What:=bidNum).Row
    womosoCol = partSheet.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="WO/MO/SO").Column
    womoso = partSheet.Cells(bidRow, womosoCol).Value
    getWOMOSO = womoso
End Function
```

Comment: It is failing to find what you are looking for, so it is returning a null object which has no `.row` property.

Comment: Are you sure, that the "BID" column has been found and that *bidCol* is valid?

Comment: When using `Find`, always specify `What`, `LookIn` and `LookAt` arguments, and test if the `Find` succeeded using the approach in the linked threads.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense thank you so much I'll give that a go